# download-db-log-file-portion is not working on .gz log files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, amazon-aurora

I am trying to download log file of writer instance using aws cli. So for that I am using `'download-db-log-file-portion'` command like this:

```
aws rds download-db-log-file-portion \
--db-instance-identifier instance_name \
--log-file-name error/postgresql.log.2023-09-21-1300.gz \
--starting-token 0 \
--output text >> directory_path
```

This rds instance has .gz extension log files. On console, I can see the log file size as 25mb but when I download it via the above command, the downloaded file size is of 223mb. Does anyone know what could be the reason behind this and how do I download the log file of 25mb?